# How to launch a custom wpf application to uninstall an application from control panel

Tags: wpf, windows-installer, uninstallation

I want to launch a custom uninstaller application(instead of default windows uninstaller) which has the ability to uninstall my msis that I have installed using my application.

I tried updating the registry value to launch the custom uninstaller.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.